# Recover custom tool presets and brushes from an expired trial of Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I used the free trial of Photoshop but forgot to export all of my tool presets and brushes. I never saved them or exported them, so they don't seem to exist in my presets files, but they clearly exist somewhere since they were always there when I started Photoshop. Is there a way I can recover them?

Comment: did you install a licensed version over your trial?

Comment: No. The trial expired and I didn't do anything else. The apps are still installed.

Answer (score 1):

Per Adobe: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/presets.html

**Default preset locations**

- The default location for saving/loading/replacing presets depends on
  your operating system.

  - **Windows 7 and Windows Vista:** [Drive]:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop[version_number]\Presets.
  - **Mac:** /Library/Application Support/Adobe/AdobePhotoshop[version_number]/Presets.
  - **Windows XP:** [Drive]:\Document and Settings\\ApplicationData\Adobe\AdobePhotoshop [version_number]\Presets.

Although the best method is to export them from the program, but with your trial expired, I would assume that's not possible.